# No polish characters in console - vscode

Tags: visual-studio-code, utf-8

I've searched the entire internet and can't find a working solution. When using vscode in javascript, I don't have Polish characters in the console. I have all files encoding set to utf8. Does anyone know what the problem could be? Everything has been fine so far, and i don't changed anything in settings.
[screen from console and vscode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4P1BZ.png)

Comment: Please [edit] your question to share a [mcve].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.